# Splunk search bunch of Strings and display table of _raw

Tags: search, field, splunk

I want to search a set of strings using OR (any better way is appreciated). Is there a way to assign name to Strings.

> index=blah host=123 "ERROR" ("FILE1" OR "FILE2" OR "FILE3" ) |  rex
>   field=_raw ".*errorDesc\":\"(?.*)\",\"errorCode.*" | table
>   _time RESP_JSON

Now, I want to add Filename as another column in table. If File is not present show empty values for rest of columns

**Note:** fileName is not a field, its just a string in _raw field

**Splunk  ::**

> [12/12/2015:12:12:12.123] **ERROR** occured while processing **FILE1**. errorDesc":"{field:123,code:124}","errorCode
>   [12/12/2015:13:13:12.123] **ERROR** occured while processing **FILE3**. errorDesc":"{field:125,code:124}","errorCode

eg Output:

**File -------------------_time  -----------------------                 RESP_JSON**

FILE1 ----- 12/12/2015:12:12:12.123 ----- {field:123,code:124}

FILE2

FILE3 ----- 12/12/2015:13:13:12.123 ----- {field:125,code:124}

No log entry for File2 is present, so empty row with just file Name is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried below to extract the filename?

```
index=blah host=123 "ERROR" ("FILE1" OR "FILE2" OR "FILE3" ) | rex field=_raw "(?<filename>). errorDesc" | table _time RESP_JSON filename
```

Regarding the first question of naming search terms have you looked at macros or using subsearchs with lookups?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  We are a question and answer site.  If you are asking questions to clarify a question, this should be done in a comment, like the one you are reading now.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
index=blah host=123 "ERROR" ("FILE1" OR "FILE2" OR "FILE3" ) | rex "processing\s+(?<filename>[^\.]+)\.\s+" | table _time RESP_JSON filename
```

It's the same search as above, just a different regex extraction.